# Dragging items out of scrollable list and preserving scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a scrolling list `overflow:auto` that has draggable items in it (jQuery UI).  When dragging items, I am temporarily turning the scrolling off (`overflow:visible`) to allow the draggable item to be visible outside the list.

http://jsfiddle.net/caseahr/8A6gj/1/

Notice that dragging an item at the top of the list works fine.  But dragging an item from the bottom of the list loses the scroll position.  Any ideas on how to make this operate more smoothly, so that the user doesn't notice the overflow CSS change very much?  I'd like the list to stay "in position" when dragging an item from the lower section of the scroll area.

Comment: Just a heads up: your fiddle doesn't work in Chrome (34). Firefox (29)  does.

Comment: I created it using Chrome 34.  Works fine in my Chrome.

Comment: Weird. I just replicated the same problem on another Win 7 computer with Chrome 34 and no extensions. Wish I could do more to help.

Comment: How about the updated link?  Thanks for trying...

Comment: It's showing up now, but behind the body because of the fixed positioning. I had to add `z-index: 10;` (10 is an arbitrary number) to the `#list-container`'s css in order for it to show up on top. Now I can do something with that! No promises though :)

Comment: So to clarify, when you say you'd like the list to 'stay in position when dragging an item from the lower section', you mean that you'd like the selected item to stay in place while the overflowing portion of the div appears *above* instead of beneath the selection? That could cause issues if that portion is then moved off the page.

Comment: Sort of.  I would like the scrolling list to stay in the scroll position regardless of where the list item was dragged from.  If you were scrolled down a little bit and picked the second item in the list, I want to scroll area to stay scrolled down the same amount when it is restored after drag stop.